# Maximum Stack Size Exceeded - Multiple AJAX problems with loops, and function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Part of my function isn't executing, I know the code is horrible I am trying to make it more efficient.

Chrome Developer Console Error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've tried to comment on what I'm trying to accomplish. I hope this helps.

I'm scraping data from a website (a large amount of data, about 6000 requests).
The script needs to get the information from, then determine if the tournament is finished, if not it just logs the tournament information into my database and then moves on.

If the tournament isn't finished I need to get the user id via ajax from my domain and then I'm going to save the information to my database and then move on to the next record.

I had to use custom loops because the ajax was screwing up the ordering.

Here is my code, let me know if you need a better explaination

```
function getTournamentInfo(){
  /** 
   *    We need to create a loop that fires AJAX only after the first request
   *    has finished so the results don't get out of order and screwed up. 
   *    Evaluate if the current tournamentid is greater than the ending id
   **/
  if (tournamentCurrentId <= tournamentEndId ) {
    // The current tournament id is less than the ending so we want to continue
    // with the funciton and get the tournament
    var data = $.getTournamentResults(tournamentCurrentId);
    //console.log(data);
    // Get the necessary information from the results and store them in their corresponding variables
    tournamentName = $.trim($(data).find('#tournament_container>h3').text());
    tournamentStatus = $.trim($(data).find('#tournament_container').clone().children().remove().end().text());
    tournamentBuyIn = $.trim($(data).find(".li_title:contains('Buy In')").parent().clone().children().remove().end().text());
    tournamentStart = $.trim($(data).find('.start').first().contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}).text());
    tournamentEnd = $.trim($(data).find('.finish').first().contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}).text());
    tournamentDuration = $(data).find('.duration2').first().contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;}).text();
    tournamentPrizePool = $.trim($(data).find(".li_title:contains('Prize Pool')").parent().clone().children().remove().end().text());
    tournamentParticipants = $.trim($(data).find(".li_title:contains('Registered Players')").parent().clone().children().remove().end().text());


    // Process variables to required mySQL format
    //tournamentStart = convertTournamentTimes(tournamentStart);
    //tournamentEnd = convertTournamentTimes(tournamentEnd);
    tournamentBuyIn = removeDollarSigns(tournamentBuyIn);
    tournamentPrizePool = removeDollarSigns(tournamentPrizePool);

    // We only want to process results for Tournaments that are finsihed,
    // excluding those that are cancelled and pending.
    // Check the tournament status and determine proper action.
    if (tournamentStatus != "Finished"){
      // The tournament is either Cancelled or Pending just store in the information in the database.

      //Temporary .append() to be replaced by SQL insert function
      $('#results').append($("<div>").append("<span>" + tournamentCurrentId + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentName + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentStatus + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentBuyIn + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentStart + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentEnd + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentDuration + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentPrizePool + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentParticipants + " </span>"));


    } else {
      // The tournament is finished we need to get the player info

      //Temporary .append() to be replaced by SQL insert function
      $('#results').append($("<div>").append("<span>" + tournamentCurrentId + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentName + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentStatus + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentBuyIn + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentStart + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentEnd + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentDuration + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentPrizePool + " </span>").append("<span>" + tournamentParticipants + " </span>"));

      // Get player info

      /** Using old fuction to test see if it works 
       *
       *  Notes:
       *
       **/

       var columns = $(data).find('#ranked_players thead th').map(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
          });

          var playerTable = $(data).find('#ranked_players tbody tr').map(function(i) {
            var row = {};
            $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
              var rowName = columns[i];
              row[rowName] = $(this).text();
            });
            return row;
          }).get();

          var columns = $(data).find('#prize_info_container table thead th').map(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
          });
          var prizeTable = $(data).find('#prize_info_container table tbody tr').map(function(i) {
            var row = {};
            $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
              var rowName = columns[i];
              row[rowName] = $.trim($(this).text());
            });
            return row;
          }).get();
          var res = $.extend(true,prizeTable,playerTable);
        console.dir(res);
        l = res.length;
        i = 0;

        function getUsableInfo(){

          playerRank = res[i].rank;
          playerName = res[i].name;
          prizeWon = res[i].prizes.replace(/\$/g, '');
          vURL = "http://www.boostlv.com/b/php/get_playerId.php?pn="+playerName;
          $.ajax({
            url: vURL,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
              playerId = data;
              $('#results').append($("<div class='players'>").text("INSERT into `a5225865_rg`.`tourn_results` (`tournamentId`, `playerId`, `playerName', `playerRank`, `prizeWon`) VALUES ('" + tournamentId + "', '" + playerId + "', '" + playerName + "', '" + playerRank + "', '" + prizeWon +"')"));
              i++;
              if(i<l){
                getUsableInfo();
              } else {
                tournamentCurrentId++;
                getTournamentInfo();
              }
            }
          });

        }
        getUsableInfo();


     }



  } else {
    // The current tournament id is the same as the ending, we have finished
    // processing all the tournaments in the range so don't do anything else

  }

    tournamentCurrentId++;
    getTournamentInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a recursive function (getTournamentInfo) with no return statement.

So what is happening:
getTournamentInfo() calls getTournamentInfo() in a loop that is never broken, until the Javascript interpreter crashes throwing an "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: Oh ok, I am trying to seperate the functions so getUsableInfo() (getPlayerInfo()) is called outside of the getTournamentInfo() function. I do however need it to loop. Can you recommend the best way to do this? Everytime I use a for loop the results get screwed up.